# JavaScript wait for two functions to finish and proceed with function three

Tags: javascript

i am trying to figure out the _callback system however don't seem to get it to work, this is what i have so far.

```
var xyz = 0;

var abc = 0;

combineData(13, 17)

function GetfromDB1(variable, _callback){
   //get request
    var abc = variable;
   _callback();
} 

function GetfromDB2(variable, _callback){
   //get request
   var xyz = variable;
   _callback();
} 

function combineData(number1, number2){

  function GetfromDB1(number1, function(){
    console.log('done')      
  });


  function GetfromDB2(number2, , function(){
    console.log('done')      
  });      

  // continue to do stuff with data

  console.log(xyz + abc) 

}
```

it seems thetwo last console log's dont wait for the callbacks and give 0 for both, how do i solve this?

Comment: Is that feasible to change the `GetFromDB` to a promise, and use `Promise.All()` at the end to resolve the promises?

Comment: there is scoping issue, you are redeclaring the functions and the variables

Comment: Please show what `//get request` does/returns. Callbacks are an old pattern; almost all usage of them are converting to promises or observables.

Comment: just a simple array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `GetfromDB1`s return Promises instead, and then you can call `Promise.all` on both calls to wait for both functions to finish:

```js
var xyz = 0;

var abc = 0;

function GetfromDB1(variable) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    //get request
    abc = 12;
    resolve();
  });
}
function GetfromDB2(variable) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    //get request
    xyz = 17;
    resolve();
  });
}
Promise.all([GetfromDB1(), GetfromDB2()])
  .then(() => {
    console.log(xyz)
    console.log(abc)
  });
```

Note that you need to assign to the *outside* variables `xyz` and `abc` - creating such variables inside the DB functions will make them be scoped locally, which won't work.

But it would be a better design if the DB functions *resolved* to the XYZ and ABC values:

```js
function GetfromDB1(variable) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    //get request
    resolve(13);
  });
}
function GetfromDB2(variable) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    //get request
    resolve(17);
  });
}
Promise.all([GetfromDB1(), GetfromDB2()])
  .then(([xyz, abc]) => {
    console.log(xyz)
    console.log(abc)
  });
```

Comment: I'd watch out for the explicit promise construction antipattern here. It might be worth getting the OP to show the actual code behind `//get request`. Otherwise, this is an example of making synchronous code async needlessly.

Comment: thanks went with the promise indeed. Both call are async so worked perfect

Answer (score 0):

There were several errors in your code:

1. You need to call GetfromDB1, not declare it again in combineData().
2. In GetfromDB1 and GetfromDB2, you need to not declare abc and xyz, else you shadow the global variable and use the local one instead that doesn't propagate to the outside

```js
var xyz = 0;

var abc = 0;

function GetfromDB1(variable, _callback){
   //get request
    abc = variable;
   _callback();
} 

function GetfromDB2(variable, _callback){
   //get request
   xyz = variable;
   _callback();
} 

function combineData(number1, number2){

  GetfromDB1(number1, function(){
    console.log('done')      
  });


  GetfromDB2(number2, function(){
    console.log('done')      
  });      
}

    combineData(13, 17)
    // continue to do stuff with data   
    console.log(xyz + abc);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). If you can't / don't want to use them, here is a solution with callbacks:

```js
var xyz = 0;

var abc = 0;

combineData(13, 17);

function GetfromDB1(variable, _callback){
   //get request
    abc = variable;
   _callback();
} 

function GetfromDB2(variable, _callback){
   //get request
   xyz = variable;
   _callback();
} 

function combineData(number1, number2){
  GetfromDB1(number1, function(){
    console.log('done 1');
    GetfromDB2(number2, function(){
      console.log('done 2');
      console.log(xyz + abc) ;
    });  
  });
}
```